# Can Garlands spoil?

Tags: dont-starve

The other day I was playing the game and noticed that at a certain point my garland stopped giving me sanity gain and the icon had a red border.  Now I may have been attacked with it on, I'm not sure, but can the garland be damaged to the point of uselessness in battle?  Can it spoil like other plants / food?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [garland](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Garland) will eventually spoil on its own.  It takes about a week.  (The wikia page says 6 days):

> The Garland spoils over time, like Food, spoiling 25% slower in winter.

This is also in the [patch notes when it was added to the game](http://steamcommunity.com/games/219740/announcements/detail/1712762439548904664):

> Garland - a pretty hat made out of flowers that gives a small sanity buff until it rots away

Comment: Okay perfect.  I thought it was spoiled but I had no idea if that was even possible.  Will that be indicated with the red border I saw on the item in my hotbar?  When it's spoiled, I assume that just means it no longer provides any sanity regeneration?

Comment: @Mkalafut, yes, I believe once rotted it stops giving you sanity back, although I think the red border just means rotting is imminent - I think mine always disappear completely once used up.

Comment: Even though the Garland gives you a Sanity increase, you may see a **Down Arrow** while wearing the Garland during evening, nights, and other freaky times.  So long that the Garland is on your head, the status does not matter, and you will receive the bonus.